# how to implement combinations in JavaScript based on object values?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to write a function to give permutations given an array of data like this:

```
 var selectedData={
        selectedAccount:"a1,a2",
        selectedYear:"2019,2018",
        selectedProduct:"p1,p2",

    }
```

I'd like a result like:

```
[
    {
        selectedAccount: "a1",
        selectedYear: "2018",
        selectedProduct: "p1",
    },
    {
        selectedAccount: "a1",
        selectedYear: "2018",
        selectedProduct: "p2",
    },
    {
        selectedAccount: "a1",
        selectedYear: "2019",
        selectedProduct: "p1",
    },
    {
        selectedAccount: "a1",
        selectedYear: "2019",
        selectedProduct: "p2",
    },
    {
        selectedAccount: "a2",
        selectedYear: "2018",
        selectedProduct: "p1",
    },
    {
        selectedAccount: "a2",
        selectedYear: "2018",
        selectedProduct: "p2",
    },
    {
        selectedAccount: "a2",
        selectedYear: "2019",
        selectedProduct: "p1",
    },
    {
        selectedAccount: "a2",
        selectedYear: "2019",
        selectedProduct: "p2",
    },
]
```

I've been struggling with some type of recursive function no luck! can anyone give ideas to acheive above result

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the lengths always going to be the same?

Comment: @its_tayo no will vary but no of fields are fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create nested `for` loops, like this:

```js
let selectedData = {
    selectedAccount: "a1,a2",
    selectedYear: "2019,2018",
    selectedProduct: "p1,p2",
};

let result = [];
for (let selectedAccount of selectedData.selectedAccount.split(",")) {
    for (let selectedYear of selectedData.selectedYear.split(",")) {
        for (let selectedProduct of selectedData.selectedProduct.split(",")) {
            result.push({ selectedAccount, selectedYear, selectedProduct });
        }
    }
}

console.log(result);
```